# how to translate おでんとか?

Tags: translation

According to Google Translate, おでんとか is "Toka Oden".  What is Toka?
What is おでんとか?

Context:

> アツアツ**おでんとか**そういうのはやらないので

Is it a name? Or is it an incorrect translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

おでん is name of a Japanese dish, which is made of daikon, fishcakes, konnyaku, kombu, etc., stewed long time. So, the phrase is アツアツ + おでん + とか ... which literally means:

- アツアツ - very hot (熱々)
- おでん - the Oden itself.
- とか - "kind of" or "etc"

so we get "Very hot Oden etc."

Comment: so Toka (とか) is etc? :)

Comment: It is an informal way to say something vaguely. For example "田中さんとか" - "Mr. Tanaka or someone else". "お菓子とか食べたい。" - I want to eat sweets or something (of that sort). "納豆とか好きです。" - "I like natto etc."